# Dynamics CRM Retrieve Message

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a request where I got to trigger a plugin to create a record every time someone opens up a record, that's for statistics stuffs.

So I just registerd my plugin on Retrieve message of the entities I need (Contact and EntityX:Which's a custom entity).

That would be working pretty good if that wasn't triggering the plugin twice (creating duplicated records).

It just happens when the plugin is running against contact entity, when it runs against my custom entity it works totally fine.

Does anyone know how to solve that issue or whether that is the expected behavior?

I've tried the following code so far:

1. if(context.Depth > 1) Which always return me the value 1

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: So... whenever a user opens a record in CRM, a record needs to be created in another entity?  If someone queries the record via the SDK, does that also need to be tracked?  Or are you only concerned when someone opens the form within CRM?

Comment: I don't quite think that's the point. That's not a problem whether the plugin is triggered through a user or via SDK. The problem is that it shouldn't run twice.. Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: its running twice because the entity is being queried once by the user, and once again in the plugin you wrote

Answer (score 1):

If all you cared about was the form, then you could do it all in js.